# North neighbor out of linked neighbors

Tags: hyperlink, netlogo

I am modelling a network in netlogo and each node has 4 linked nodes (like a mesh). I want to take some value from only the left (west) **linked** node. How do I do this? If I say `link-neighbors` then all the linked neighbors get selected but I want to do this operation on only specific linked neighbor.

Comment: Are your nodes fixed to patches? Normally, a network does not recognise a spatial orientation because edges just mean that some relationship exists between individuals. For example, in a transport network, the orientation comes from the location of the airport or train station.

Comment: Yes, my nodes are fixed to patches. But depending on my network, my left neighbor can be at -1,0 or -1,-1. I have 4 neighbors. Is there a way to number the **linked** neighbors in say, clockwise direction maybe and then refer to them accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Since your nodes are fixed to patches, you can take advantage of the in-built coordinate system. All nodes have a pair of variables `xcor` and `ycor`, and patches have `pxcor` and `pycor`. If your nodes are always exactly in the centre of a patch, you could simply find the `link-neighbor` with the `xcor` that is exactly 1 less than the `xcor` of the asking node. But a more general solution is to find the linked node that is most to the west (which is equivalent to the one with the lowest value for `xcor`).

Here is some (untested) example code that just colours a node and its west neighbour, and prints a variable value of the west neighbour.

```
ask one-of nodes
[ set color red
  let left-node min-one-of link-neighbors [xcor]
  ask left-node [ set color blue ]
  type "Colour of west node is: " print [color] of left-node
]
```